# Proving that if there is a constant $B$ such that $|f(x)-f(c)|\leq B|x-c|$ for all $x\in(c-p, c+p)$, then $f$ is continuous at $x=c$.

Tags: calculus

Suppose the function $f$ has the property that there exists a number $B$ such that $|f(x)-f(c)|\leq B|x-c|$ for all $x$ in the interval $(c-p, c+p)$. Prove that $f$ is continuous at $c$.

Comment: This question lacks context. Don't just post a problem statement. You need to say what you've tried.

Comment: Please share your work for this so that others can help better.

Comment: I want to apply this theorem: Suppose f is cont. at c. If f(c)>0, then there exists a δ such at f(x)>0 on (c-δ,c+δ)

Comment: What is p in your question?

Comment: But can you apply that theorem? B'coz in that theorem continuity of f is a hypothesis while in your question you ought to prove the continuity of f!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Definition.** A function $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined near a point $c\in\mathbb{R}$ if there is $\delta>0$ such that
>   $$
> \{x:0<|x-c|<\delta\}\subseteq I
> $$
>
> **Defintion.** Let $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined near $c\in I$. $f$ is continuous at $x=c$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a corresponding $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$
>   $$
> |x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon
> $$

Notice that there is $\delta>0$ (you need to take $\delta\leq p$) such that
$$
(c-\delta,c)\cup(c,c+\delta)\subseteq (c-p,c+p)
$$
so $f$ is defined near $c$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. We must find $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$
$$
|x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon
$$
Let's approximate $|f(x)-f(c)|$.

$$
|f(x)-f(c)|\leq B|x-c|
$$
We want to make $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$ so we need to make $B|x-c|<\epsilon$ which forces $|x-c|<\frac{\epsilon}{B}$. This suggests that we need to take $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{B}$. Then
$$
|x-c|<\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{B}\Rightarrow
|f(x)-f(c)|\leq B|x-c|<B\frac{\epsilon}{B}=\epsilon
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $ \epsilon >0$, then $\delta=\epsilon/B$

(I suppose that $B>0$).

Answer (score 0):

It is just a direct application of definition of continuity at a point.
Given $\epsilon>0$, take $\delta=\frac {\epsilon}{B} $ in the definition.